# Setup.msi solicita ao utilizador instalar o .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Tenho um pacote *.msi de um software desenvolvido por mim, com o Visual Studio Setup Project.

Quando um utilizador tenta executar na sua máquina o pacote de instalação e este não tem instalada a versão 4.6.1 do .NET Framework, surge uma mensagem a informar que o mesmo não existe e um botão para instalar.

O grande problema é que este botão redirecciona o utilizador para a pagina de instalação do .NET Framework 4.5

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

O que está incorrecto, o correcto seria:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981

O resultado disto é que o utilizador sem conhecimento instala a versão 4.5, volta a executar o setup.msi e o problema persiste, tornando-se um ciclo infinito sem resolução!

Alguma ajuda?

Pelo que já investiguei, o Setup Project do Visual Studio cria um pacote msi e um exe. Este exe é um projecto à parte que serve para verificar os pré-requisitos do PC do user e instala (correctamente) o que está em falta.

O problema é que isto resulta em dois ficheiros um msi e um exe. Será que há forma de empacotar tudo apenas no msi?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se não for realmente necessário, evite usar a última versão do framework, usa uma mais popular, assim a instalação fica mais simples para o usuário.

Com o Visual Studio Setup Project acho que você pode tentar colocar o .net 4.6.1 nos pré-requisitos, aqui tem uma explicação de como fazer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx